# How to add a button within a dropdown menu?

Tags: reactjs, forms, button, semantic-ui

I joined an ongoing react project for entering case studies. We are using semantic-ui for forms and form dropdowns. What I want to do is add a button within the drop-down that will initiate another menu.

[I want to add the button to this dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkDWk.png)

I'm unsure of where to add the code for the button or if it's even possible.
Here is the current code for the dropdowns:

````
          <h1 className="ui centered">Select Engagement Details</h1>
          <Form.Group widths="equal">
            <Form.Dropdown
              fluid
              selection
              placeholder="Client Name"
              onChange={(e, { value }) => {
                this.props.handleDropdown({
                  input: "clientName",
                  value: value,
                  optionType: "clientOptions",
                  options: this.state.clients
                });
              }}
              defaultValue={values.clientName}
              options={this.state.clients}
            />

            <Form.Dropdown
              fluid
              selection
              placeholder="Engagement Name"
              onChange={(e, { value }) => {
                this.props.handleDropdown({
                  value: value,
                  input: "engagementName",
                  optionType: "engagementNameOptions",
                  options: this.state.engagements
                });
              }}
              defaultValue={values.engagementName}
              options={this.state.engagements}
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <Button disabled={!isEnabled} onClick={this.saveAndContinue}>
            {" "}
            Continue
          </Button>

          {/* starts new engagement area */}
          <hr style={{marginTop: '30px'}}/>
          <h2 className="ui centered"> New Engagement </h2>

          <Form.Group controlId="newEngagementGroup" widths="equal">
            {/* type is not required. Type is useful for common types like "email" or "password" */}
            <Form.Input 
                  type="clientName" 
                  placeholder="Enter Client Name"
                  ref="newClient"
                  onChange={(e, { value }) => {
                    this.props.handleDropdown({
                      input: "newEngagementClientName",
                      value: value
                    })
                  }}
                  defaultValue={values.newClientName}
            />
            <Form.Input 
                  type="engagementType" 
                  placeholder="Enter Engagement Type"
                  ref="newEngagementType"
                  onChange={(e, { value }) => {
                    this.props.handleDropdown({
                      input: "newEngagementType",
                      value: value
                    })
                  }}
                  defaultValue={values.newEngagementType} />
          </Form.Group>```
````

Answer (score 0):

it's possible:

had your button to your options list

`options={[{ key: "ux", text: (<Button>your button</Button>), value: "ux" }]}`

Comment: Okay, but then how do I also include my props as an option? Currently the options are, ```{this.state.clients}``` How do I include that as well as the button? Thank you

Comment: You can't change clients ?

Comment: What do you mean change clients? I am new to this project and react development in general. Here is how I declared clients:                                                             ```state = { 
    clients: [], 
    engagements: [],
    newClientName: "",
    newEngagementType: "",
  };```