# Adding a button/icon to each row of a Semantic UI React dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

Related to this question [How to add a button within a dropdown menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61356535/how-to-add-a-button-within-a-dropdown-menu)

[Working Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/little-glade-pvcbd?file=/src/App.js)

I have a Semantic UI React Dropdown and I want to place a little, clickable, delete icon on each row of the dropdown, similar to this photo.

[image: Rows of data with delete icons on each row]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do like this

```
   <Dropdown
text='Filter'
icon='filter'
floating
labeled
button
className='icon'
>
 <Dropdown.Menu>
  <Dropdown.Header icon='tags' content='Filter by tag' />
  <Dropdown.Divider />
  <Dropdown.Item>
    <Icon name='attention' className='right floated' />
    Important
  </Dropdown.Item>
  <Dropdown.Item>
    <Icon name='comment' className='right floated' />
    Announcement
  </Dropdown.Item>
  <Dropdown.Item>
    <Icon name='conversation' className='right floated' />
    Discussion
  </Dropdown.Item>
</Dropdown.Menu>
</Dropdown>
```

if you have some dynamic data then simple map it

```
<Dropdown
text='Filter'
icon='filter'
floating
labeled
button
className='icon'
 >
<Dropdown.Menu>
  <Dropdown.Header icon='tags' content='Filter by tag' />
  <Dropdown.Divider />

  {
    options.map(item => <Dropdown.Item>
    <Icon name={item.icon} className='right floated' />
    {item.name}
    </Dropdown.Item>)

  }
 </Dropdown.Menu>
</Dropdown>
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you for the response! I added a <Button> instead of an <Icon> but you showed me what I was missing, a <Dropdown.Menu>

Comment: The problem I'm having now is that clicking a menu option doesn't update the Dropdown itself. The Dropdown doesn't seem to hear option selections.